When, where, and how did Laszlo Toth die?
Laszlo Toth was famous for trying to destroy the Pieta in 1972.


I'm curious what is actually known about the circumstances of his death. His Wikipedia page suspiciously doesn't provide the usual death information in their biographical bar on the right. The body text does say he "passed his later years in a rest home in Strathfield NSW", but doesn't give a date.
There are two references given for that line. The first is a blog post written by what appears to be a professional Catholic blogger. Based on the dates of the comments, it was written in 2012:

He resides in a nursing home in Strathfield, NSW, Australia.

The second is a magazine article from 2023 in a publication billing itself as an English-language magazine for expatriates living in Rome. It refers to Toth as:

reportedly living a hermit-like existence in a remote part of New
South Wales. Toth died on 11 September 2012.

I don't like the fuzzyness of "reportedly" there, but it does give us a date of death. I find it weird that it wasn't trusted enough to put in the WP page. It also seems rather like these two sources were taken at face value and combined to arrive at the conclusion he died in the nursing home the first article said he was living in.
Normally I'd just look for other sources. This is a fairly famous guy, so they should exist. However, I'm having trouble there. Mostly what I'm finding is anecdotal reports on chat sites, which are often contradictory and rather remind me of all the early 80's post-mortem Elvis sightings. That makes me even more suspicious of the two sources WP gave.
I'm wondering if we have any better and or more consistent sources about the circumstances of Laszlo Toth's death.

I got to thinking about Toth due to a recent similarly appalling attack on the Magna Carta, carried out by a couple of ladies who appear to have been born around the right time (but not place!) to have been sisters of Toth.

I’m not sure I’d call him ‘fairly famous’. Not even infamous either.

@JonCuster - I'd say on the obscure end of famous. Like "Dancing with the Stars" famous, not A-list famous. He's famous enough that his name lept to mind when I saw that article. I've heard people compared to him a lot of my life. Dennis Miller used him as an adjective in a rant, although Miller was pretty well known for super-obscure references I guess.

Fair enough. I’m old enough to remember the incident, but not the hammer-wielder’s name.

Another guy with his 15mn of glory, but is it "famous" or "infamous", TITQ...

@T.E.D. "I find it weird that it wasn't trusted enough to put in the WP page." - Then you should put it in the Wikipedia page. :)

Legacy.com says his obituary was published in The West Australian. It might take some effort to track that down.

@OldPadawan - I'd argue that "infamous" is a subset of "famous", but the former certainly applies here too.

@BrianZ For Australian newspapers I usually try Trove first, but it does not seem to be available there. Until recently, The West Australian digital archive was apparently available online, but as of December 2023 access has been limited to computers of the State Library of Western Australia. Anybody here planning a visit to Perth in the near future?

Laszlo Toth is a fairly common Hungarian name. For example, there are at least TWO Hungarian artists by that name whose artworks are sold in Australia. So, the Laszlo Toth who died in West Australia in 2012 is not necessarily the deranged Laszlo Toth who vandalised the Pieta in 1972.

Any evidence either way?

Not doubting you, but using that exact name combo after what happened seems an odd choice. Like an American naming their child "John Brown" or "Jim Jones".

@T.E.D. Jim Jones is an incredibly popular name in America, as evidence by many profiles found on LinkedIn.

@cmw - Hopefully those folks are mostly over the age of 50, rather than had clueless parents.

I was reminded of this because László Tóth is the name of the main character in the new movie The Brutalist.
